# Unable to reinstall Aoe Scheduler

Tags: magento-1.9, installation, uninstall, email-scheduler

Yesterday I have Uploaded files of Aoe scheduler (which I had downloaded from GitHub) through FTP on my project.

But when I setup schedules from admin, it wasn't working. I got error in report files as "last_seen" column (and some other column names) are missing in the table cron_schedule (I checked into DB and yes they were not there).

So, to fix this I have dropped the table through php myadmin, downloaded Aoe scheduler V 1.5.0 from [here](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler/releases/tag/v1.5.0) and uploaded these fresh files to replace the previous ones.

But, now the issue is that the cron_shedule table is not at all being created in database. so the schedular options are not working in backend.

I need to reinstall this module to make emails work.

Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have not deleted entry from `core_resource` table

So go to phpmyadmin and find `core_resource` table.

Fire the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `core_resource` WHERE `code` = 'aoescheduler_setup'
```

And delete this record.

Now your install schema will run again.

Comment: Yes I did what you have just mentioned but now after generating schedules from admin, The timeline page and List view pages are showing blank

Comment: uncomment line in your `index.php` in root folder `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I have just selected "Queue usage" as "never" from SMTP pro and disabled the scheduler module from its XML file.
Thanks For your help.

Comment: @WasiqShahrukh if my answer help you to solve your problem you can mark as accepted , this will help other people who find same problem